# Predictive features with high presence in one class

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am doing a logistic regression to predict the outcome of a binary variable, say whether a journal paper gets accepted or not. The dependent variable or predictors are all the phrases used in these papers - (unigrams, bigrams, trigrams). One of these phrases has a skewed presence in the 'accepted' class. Including this phrase gives me a classifier with a very high accuracy (more than 90%), while removing this phrase results in accuracy dropping to about 70%. 
My more general (naive) machine learning question is:
Is it advisable to remove such skewed features when doing classification?
Is there a method to check skewed presence for every feature and then decide whether to keep it in the model or not?

Comment: There's cross-validation, which can be used to check for overfitting. What makes you say the feature is "skewed"? It might be an actual predictor of papers getting accepted or not. (I'm wondering what the phrase is.)

Comment: I am doing cross-validation to check for overfitting. That is not the issue. When I say feature is "skewed", I mean that the feature has a very high occurrence in one of the classes. Example of the feature having high occurrence in the "accepted" class and almost no occurrence in the "not accepted" class is -- "paper accepted on".

Comment: If you want to identify paper already published, then a phrase like "paper accepted on" is good. If on the other hand you want to predict if a submitted paper will be accepted, then this phrase is a "leak from the future" and must be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you ask whether some feature should be removed because it is **a good** predictor (it makes your classifier works better). So the answer is short and simple - **do not remove it** in fact, the whole concept is to find **exactly such** features.

The only reason to remove such feature would be that this phenomena only occurs in the training set, and not in real data. But in such case you have wrong data - which does not represnt the underlying data density and you should gather better data or "clean" the current one so it has analogous characteristics as the "real ones".

Comment: +1; it's important to point out that such features are *not* harmless, as regularization might press actually predictive features toward zero.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, it sounds like the feature in your documents that's highly predictive of the class is a near-tautology: "paper accepted on" correlates with accepted papers because at least some of the papers in your database were scraped from already-accepted papers and have been annotated by the authors as such.

To me, this sounds like a useless feature for trying to predict whether a paper will be accepted, because (I'd imagine) you're trying to predict paper acceptance *before* the actual acceptance has been issued ! In such a case, none of the papers you'd like to test your algorithm with will be annotated with "paper accepted on." So, I'd remove it.

You also asked about how to determine whether a feature correlates strongly with one class. There are three things that come to mind for this problem.

First, you could just compute a basic frequency count for each feature in your dataset and compare those values across classes. This is probably not super informative, but it's easy.

Second, since you're using a log-linear model, you can train your model on your training dataset, and then rank each feature in your model by its weight in the logistic regression parameter vector. Features with high positive weight are indicative of one class, while features with large negative weight are strongly indicative of the other.

Finally, just for the sake of completeness, I'll point out that you might also want to look into [**feature selection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection). There are many ways of selecting relevant features for a machine learning algorithm, but I think one of the most intuitive from your perspective might be **greedy feature elimination**. In such an approach, you train a classifier using all N features in your model, and measure the accuracy on some held-out validation set. Then, train N new models, each with N-1 features, such that each model eliminates one of the N features, and measure the resulting drop in accuracy. The feature with the biggest drop was probably strongly predictive of the class, while features that have no measurable difference can probably be omitted from your final model. As larsmans points out correctly in the comments below, this doesn't scale well at all, but it can be a useful method sometimes.

Comment: Your proposed algorithm is going to scale poorly in text classification, where the number of features is typically on the order of thousands to millions. Also, feature selection would typically *keep* the "paper accepted on" feature, so I don't see how it relates to the OP's problem.

Comment: @larsmans I agree with both your points and also the tautology which lmjohns3 indicated. Other than removing such tautology by hand, I don't seem to find any algorithmic method to do this.